# Unable to connect to wireless network on my sony F15218 laptop with ubuntu 12.04 lts 64 bit

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, 64-bit

I have been trying since yesterday to get wifi working on my laptop.
it was working fine till yesterday but has stopped working now.
Actually the problem is it's not able to find my home wifi.
It doesn't show my home wifi at all. I changed my modem yesterday and since then it has stopped working.
I have done various things and it's all messed up as of now.

This is the configuration of my Driver :

```
Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

Earlier I had installed the driver exactly as given over here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43142

The internet worked fine but when I changed my modem yesterday my laptop wasn't able to detect the new modem/wifi but the wifi works fine on my phone so the modem is configured fine.
I followed quite a few things online but nothing seems to work.

This **http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7886319/** is the output of the script I ran according to this link **[My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)**

And the out put of the following code

```
sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source
```

is on this link -->> **pastebin.ubuntu.com/7890911/**

Can someone please help.

Comment: Install your driver then Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: @Wild Man I did as you said and as I have installed the driver again, it doesn't detect my network but detects other networks. I am not sure if it will connect to those networks can't even test as I don't have the security key . ANd here is the output of the script : [output](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7886319/)

Comment: There s an error message with the driver, where did you get it from? What is the name of your network?

Comment: The name of my network is **gautam**, which isn't visible as you can see in the output.

Comment: Where is the error message? I couldn't identify.

Comment: This is the error message ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power : error (-1). Post the output of `sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source`

Comment: Here is the output..[output](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7890911/)

Comment: @Wild Man ..I have posted the output as you said,can you please guide me with this.

Comment: I am sorry it is taking me so long to reply I am in the country right now and my ubuntu is down and I am having to use windows with a very bad internet connection. Is the new modem a router also? I recommend resetting the modem and router removing your network from network manager and rebooting the computer.

Comment: Also run: `echo "blacklist brcmutil" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` then: `sudo gedit etc/modules` remove brcmutil then save the file and reboot.

Comment: I did some things and at the present moment wifi detects some networks but doesn't detect my home network.   How can I go about this? How should I have the wifi detect my home network

Comment: Yes my modem is a router as well. Can be used as a wifi and can also be connected as a wired connection

Comment: Thank God. It finally works..resetting the modem identified my home network. And just to tell you earlier kernel in use was bcma-pci-bridge cause of which my internet had stopped working.. Thank you so much wild man. You are a genius. Sorry but can't up vote as there are just comments and no answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run in the terminal:

```
echo "blacklist brcmutil" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Then:

```
sudo gedit etc/modules
```

and  from that file remove brcmutil then save the file and reboot.

Reset the modem and router remove your network from network manager and reboot the computer to allow network manager to find your network.

Comment: I also blacklisted bcma,brcmsmac,bcma-pci-bridge and removed brcmsmac from `etc/modules`.

Comment: My wifi has stopped working again..it's not able to detect my home network..can you please help.

Comment: This is the output of the script for the present situation (http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7953685/)

Comment: Please help me man..I am clueless at this point of time

Comment: I am working out of town i can not get on my computer until tonight i will look then.

Comment: ok..please do, do you want me to provide any other information?

Comment: No just the new output from the script

Comment: I have already posted the link of the output of the script(5 comments above)..wifi is working as in it shows other networks but doesn't show my home network. Don't know if I connect to other networks will it work or not(can't try since don't have the password of other networks)

Comment: Is your network hidden?

Comment: no..my network is not hidden and it connects and works fine on my phone

Comment: Did you have new updates installed? did you add any new parameters to your driver? or do anything that someone told you to do?

Comment: No didn't add anything..actually what happens is see this question I posted yesterday before my laptop stopped recognizing the wifi http://askubuntu.com/questions/506711/wifi-problems-with-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: One more thing if I just reset the modem my home network(name -> brainstorm) is detected but I am not able to connect, but if I change the name of my home network my laptop doesn't even recognize it but my phone does.

Comment: You have changed the name of the network then remove all networks from network manager and reboot computer.

Comment: I have already tried this but this doesn't work.